# Xcode 6.3.2 convert to latest Swift syntax hangs

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, swift2

I upgraded to Xcode 6.3.2 and tried to run "Convert to latest Swift syntax" on my project, but it hangs.

[image: Screenshot added]

The "Generating preview..." window appears and spins and spins, but never completes.

I tried the "Convert to latest Swift syntax" on another project, and it worked just fine. That project is mostly Objective-C but has some Swift files including a Watch extension.

I have installed the latest command-line tools (although that really shouldn't be necessary, should it?), deleted Derived Data, cleaned the project, restarted Xcode, restarted my computer, all numerous times, but Xcode still hangs.

I cannot build my project. It gets the point where it says "Compiling Swift source files" and never gets any farther.

Any ideas on what else to try, where to look for clues?

Comment: While it spins, my hard drive sounds like an airplane about to take off.

Comment: Same thing happens to me and has been happening for a while. I try to convert the project to the latest Swift syntax and it shows me a preview of what's getting converted, yet it never successfully converts the project. Mind... Blown. Happens with my iMac as well as my macbook pro. Very curious as to how everyone else gets this to work.

Comment: I suspect there must be something unique about our projects. Can you think of anything you are doing in your project that might seem out of the ordinary? Do you have any other projects that successfully convert?

Comment: So basically I noticed that there are some conversions going through, but not all. Really weird. Nothing out of the ordinary I'm doing - just simply firing up a project and selecting the option to convert.

Answer (score 0):

It was very slow for me xcode7-beta even when I have only one swift file and rest all objective-c but it finally converted and showed me that there are no changes and then the project failed to build. Without coverting the project works fine for me. This is probably not an answer but this website is not allowing me to add a comment yet.